# Adding filter data-placeholder in jquery tablesorter

Tags: tablesorter, filterfunction

Is there a way to add data-placeholder values through the table sorter jquery syntax rather than adding to the th HTML tag itself? Perhaps using the headers syntax like with filter: false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are five ways to disable a column filter ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/816/)):

HTML (showing 3 ways)

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
            <th class="filter-false">Numeric</th> <!-- class name -->
            <th class='{ "filter": false }'>Numeric2</th> <!-- meta data (requires metadata plugin) -->
            <th data-filter="false">Animals</th> <!-- data-attribute -->
            <th>Sites</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script (showing 2 ways)

```
$(function(){
  // jQuery data (Sites column)
  $('table').find('th:eq(4)').data('filter', false);

  $('table').tablesorter({
      theme: 'blackice',
      headers: {
          0: { filter: false } // headers option (Alphanumeric column)
      },
      widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
  });
});
```

---

Oops, sorry I'm tired; long day. To add a placeholder to the filter, use either of these methods:

```
<th data-placeholder="Enter something...">AlphaNumeric</th>
```

or using script

```
// target the column using eq(0), where the number is a zero-based index of the column
$('.tablesorter th:eq(0)').data('placeholder', 'Enter something...');
```

Comment: Ugh, once again... told you I'm tired. The `data('placeholder', '...')` won't work yet, but I'll include it in the next update. Sorry!!

Comment: No problem - thanks for the quick response. Look forward to the next update!